# Comparing checksums and finding differences

Tags: java, jar, checksum

Is there a way to find the differences between multiple jar files when their checksum is different?

Based on an escrow agreement, my live code needs to be the same as the latest release from the developer. I compared the jar file using FastSum and I have differences in the checksums. How can I find where those differences are?

Is there a tool for this?

Comment: jar=>java (in my head) - if so, please add that tag. If not, please edit a different tag to identify the technology. Since what you really want help with, I gather, is finding differences between jars.

Comment: as requested. thanks

Comment: What do you compare? Who build the JARs you compare? How where they built?

Comment: Jars are buld using Netbean/Eclipse and deployed on a Jboss/Apache setup

Comment: Just remember, due to timestamps, each time you recompile and rebuild the checksum of the jar will be different, even though there was no changes in code.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are compressed zip archives so you need to unzip both jar files which results in two folders with multiple files in it. For each file of one folder you now check if this file exists in the other as well and if yes, if the contents are the same.

Comment: yes i know that process...i am looking for a tool that does that automatically to tell me i.e  in file a line 332 is different from file b...

Answer (score 0):

one could use BeyondCompare software to compare War/Jar diretly